# The "more..." link on the Completeness Score on Careers doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The Completeness Score page on Careers has a number of "more..." links which is supposed to show "Show places to improve". However, clicking this link doesn't do anything.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdQTr.jpg]

Comment: what browser do you use? is it in "officially supported list? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: I tested with the latest version of Chrome and Firefox. Great picture by the way; thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like we broke some JS on that page.  This should be working now.